# Fragment application, how to add a footer?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, tabs

I'm working on an Android application with 4 tabs.

Here is my activity_main.xml

```
 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/pager"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

 </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

And here is one of my tab (they are all the same for the moment)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:background="#ff8400" >

     <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:text="Top Screen"
         android:textSize="20dp"
         android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>


 </RelativeLayout>
```

How could I add a footer that would be visible on each tab?

It's to add a player that stays visible while scrolling the tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to make a change to your main activity layout. You can do it with a LinearLayout or RelativeLayout. Because a LinearLayout is less expensive I will show you that here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/music_player"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The view could been anything, I would recommend using a framelayout there and putting in a fragment if it is going to be as complicated as a music player. How this works is you set the height of the musicplayer (wrap_content) and you tell the pager to take up the rest of the space with layout_height="0dp" and layout_weight="1".

If you want to do a RelativeLayout then the musicplayer would alignParentBottom="true" and the pager would have layout_above="@+id/music_player with either layout_height="matchparent" or alignParentTop="true".