# How to set up footer in in a android fragment?

Tags: android, footer, user-experience

I want to set a footer in android fragment. I am using appcomat for action bar and would like to have a bar simialr to action bar with as footer.

Footer will display some information as text .It wont have any clickable buttons.

[image]

I have create a mockup of footer as shown below.This will then contain some text.
Note the color of footer should be same as action bar.

Also  the UI looks very ugly.How can i make it better?

Comment: Have you noticed the dummy textview that was generated when you create a ViewPager layout? You can modify it and set up your footer.

Comment: @jyoon :TextView with alignParentBottom = true ? But how do i use same color as action bar ?How can i reuse style?

Comment: Um, android:textColor="whatever text color you wish", in your case, it seems like #ffffff

Comment: I dont want to use "whatever text color you wish" .I want to reuse the style of actionbar.

Comment: The color in your picture seems to be `#ff202020` (as detected by ColorCop). Anyway, I guess you can get and set the ActionBar color, as well as that of any other View

Comment: Where do i find color style that is used by appcombar lib?

Comment: Refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20913872/android-fragment-application-how-to-add-a-footer

Comment: You can force it in styles.xml, as this post shows (OK, it's for the foreground color, but you can easily adapt it for the background color): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22353414/how-to-change-color-of-actionbars-title-text-on-android-4-3-api-18

Comment: OK, you might want to see this for the colours. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10382463/3463021

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answering my own question : I found the following way better.

Use nested layouts

[Android: 2 relative layout divided in half screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19983335/android-2-relative-layout-divided-in-half-screen)